# Sending mail using user's configured email account

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net Contact us page.
Here we have provided email address to user which they can use to contact us.

Now I have to make this email address clickable and on clicking it user should able to send us mail using his configured mail account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add like this

```
<a href="mailto:EmailID@.com">EmailID@.com</a>
```

Comment: this will open outlook with configure EmailID

Comment: or whichever other email client they have set to be default.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple email form and do not expose email address to screen scrapers on your website, ever. Spam blocking is only partially effective; I've seen servers brought to their knees over this kind of practice.

Answer (score 0):

Add your email addess to an  tag and add call a javascript on client click  to show up a popup .
which allows user to enter his email address and message.
a button provided at the end of opup can be used to send the email.

Eg:  email address